# Is there a way for a query to override the "-e" (ECHO INPUT) option to SQLCMD?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

With SQL Server, the "-e" option to SQLCMD causes input (source) to get echoed.  I have a specific .SQL file where I don't want the input echoed -- I just want the results.  Does SQL Server have equivalent of "SET ECHO OFF" ??

Comment: No such thing as `SET ECHO OFF` in batch files either.

Comment: Ummm, what is wrong with simply removing the `-e` option when you execute that particular script?

Comment: @dbenham: The "sqlcmd" is in a batch file.  There's multiple batch files that need to be replicated (more-or-less) across multiple servers in multiple environments.  "just one more batch file without -e" snowballs into a lot of files.

Comment: I don't think there is a script command to override `-e`, and even if there were, I don't see how that would be easier to implement across multiple scripts than modifying the call to remove the `-e` command line option.